# SQL Find entries across two tables with circular references

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have two tables, one is a header table which defines the 'parent' object and the other is a 'child' table which defines multiple child entries which are related to a parent entity.

The parent entity can contain both individual children(which are single items) or a parent item (which is made up of multiple items)

I need to find out which parents have references to children which are also parents whos children have circular references to parents
IE

> Parent 1
>
> > Parent 2(a child)

> Parent 2
>
> > Parent 3(a child)

> Parent 3
>
> > Parent 1(a child) - circular

a simple table structure is

Table 1

| BOMID | PARTCODE (This is the part code for the BOMID, which is also treated as a normal part code) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

Table 2

| BOMID | PARTCODE (This is a column for partcodes(can be a normal partcode or a BOM partcode) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | abc123 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

I am looking to find Bill of Materials with circular references (not sure everyone will know what Bill of Materials is but it might help.)

Comment: BoMs are *typically* easy to calculate with recursive CTEs, but finding circular references is more difficult. I'm actually curious how a circular reference on a BoM happens in practice for you, as I've never encountered one in practice. Which database system are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: The database the information is stored in is Informix and managed by Pronto. I will be copying data down with Openquery to SQL Server 15 and doing queries there.

Comment: Gotcha. SQL Server 15 isn't a version that exists. Do you mean 2014 by any chance?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125) - 15.0.2101.7